# Can Logitech K310 keyboard be washed with one of its keys removed?

Tags: cleaning, logitech-keyboard, water-damage

Logitech K310 is claimed to be washable with certain limitations (warm water with mild soap only, no submersion deeper that 30 centimeters below water surface, USB plug is excluded).

However I have K310 with one of the keys removed (and I'd rather not install it back). Specifically the white cap with the key name is removed entirely, all the other parts are still there, no signs of mechanical damage.

Is it still washable (with the same limitations of course)?

Comment: This isn't an answer of course, but I've washed it twice so far both times with the key detached and it's still fine. YMMV.